# How can I share a post of my game on Facebook using Unity3D and FacebookSDK?

Tags: c#, android, facebook, unity-game-engine, mobile

I am developing a 2D game in Unity and I would like to share a high score post on Facebook, which would have a title, description and also an print screen and a link that would redirect Facebook user's to the Play Store app page.

However, no matter what I do both methods provided by the FacebookSDK v7.17.2 package to share info on the user's feed (ShareLink and FeedShare) seem to make the link URI the main content and it totally ignores the rest of the information I try to use.

Does anyone had this problem and found a solution?

Using ShareLink:

```
public void FacebookShare(int score)
{
    FB.ShareLink(
        contentTitle: "TESTS",
        contentDescription: "THIS IS A FACEBOOK SDK TEST",
        contentURL: new System.Uri("https://www.nonsenseuri.com.br"),
        callback: ShareCallback
        );
}

private void ShareCallback(IShareResult result)
{
    if (result.Cancelled || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
        Debug.Log("Share feature error: " + result.Error);

    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.PostId))
        Debug.Log(result.PostId);

    else
        Debug.Log("Share success");
}
```

[Result of ShareLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuB94.jpg)

Using FeedShare:

```
public void FacebookShare(int score)
{
    FB.FeedShare(
        link: new System.Uri("https://www.nonsenseuri.com.br"),
        linkName: "Test Link",
        linkCaption: "I played for " + score + "seconds!",
        linkDescription: "Test Description",
        callback: ShareCallback);
}

private void ShareCallback(IShareResult result)
{
    if (result.Cancelled || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
        Debug.Log("Share feature error: " + result.Error);

    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.PostId))
        Debug.Log(result.PostId);

    else
        Debug.Log("Share success");
}
```

[Result of FeedShare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be47I.jpg)

In the examples I removed personal information, but these are the results I've obtained by running each code snippet. It seems like the FacebookSDK changed the way we share posts with Unity and now we have to use an HTML page (?) The documentation does not specify anything in this regard, can someone confirm this?

Comment: Could yo please provide a snippet of your code and the results you're getting?

Comment: Sure! Just added it to the question description

Comment: You can not specify title, description or thumbnail dynamically at the time of sharing any more. All this information will be taken from the OG meta tags the shared URL returns. If you want to share anything “customized”, like containing a user’s personal score - then you need to create an individual URL explicitly for each case, that returns the correct meta data.

Comment: So to make it work I'd have to create a URL which gets and HTML file with the desired meta tags? I'm not sure how to do it though, sorry, how does one "create a URL"?